# Remove "Brave does not review extensions for security" warning in my chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store, brave

So I have this chrome extension. (Have removed the link so it doesn't seem like promotion)

And when I try to install it, gives the following warning:

[image: brave warning security extension utility one by shubham kushwah]

I do not collect any user data, or modify the data on the youtube page, it's only a floating element in the top section.

Is there a way I can suppress this warning by changing something in the chrome webstore dashboard? Because this makes the extension sound suspicious.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No. As the popup says, Brave does not review the code of the extensions, so the only way to know that you are not actually collecting or modifying data is to trust you and believe that you really do what you're saying.

Comment: @Bergi I understand that, but why do I not see that warning when installing extensions like Grammarly, and Honey, which are doing the same thing by modifying the page's content to show their popup?

Comment: Have you already asked your question on the Brave forums? Because that is probably a more appropriate place to ask questions about Brave-specific warnings.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question here...

There doesn't seem to be a way around this, since it's happening for even the biggest Chrome extensions on the store.

So I guess we'll have to live with the warning.